# PHP date/time function not work properly?

Tags: php, date, time

**Why the following two will get same Result??**

echo date('d/m/Y',1338156000); will produce output **28/05/2012**

And echo date('d/m/Y',1338143400); also produce the same out put **28/05/2012**  ??

Comment: Because those times are 3.5 hours apart - they both reside on the same day.

Comment: it gives me the different output `28/05/2012` and
`27/05/2012`

Comment: @SumitBijvani could be due to the DST settings

Comment: 1338156000 and 1338143400 are seconds. In your case both the seconds lie on the same day.

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ yeah you are right :)

Comment: if timezone is set to UTC it will display 27/05/2012 for both statement ...

Answer (score 2):

Difference of this values is 3.5 hours. So, it is times of one day.

Answer (score 2):

Quite Simple

```
<?php 
    echo date('d/m/Y',1338156000); 
    echo "<br />";
    echo date('d/m/Y',1338143400); 
    echo "<br />";

    echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s',1338156000); 
    echo "<br />";
    echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s',1338143400); 
    echo "<br />";


?>
```

Here, when 27/05/2012 22:00:00 the day is: 27

and when 27/05/2012 18:30:00 the day is: 27

Answer (score 2):

Yes Both will give the same date because time stamp  is in seconds.if you print first like

```
echo date("d/m/y h:i:s", 1338156000);
```

it will give you result like

```
28/05/2012 03:30:00
```

and

```
echo date('d/m/Y h:i:s',1338143400);
```

result is

```
28/05/2012 12:00:00
```

for further reference check php date and time manual

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others, its the same date that's why the confusion. But if you simply add time to your own code along with the date your confusion will itself be gone without asking.

```
<?php
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s',1338156000);
echo "<br>";
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s',1338143400);
?>
```